# How to construct a const char *buffer for send() function of winsock

Tags: c++, networking, hook, winsock, winsock2

I hooked the send function but I'm receiving errors from the server. The server says that I'm sending an invalid packet.

What's the right way to construct a const char *buffer for the send function?

I want to construct a buffer from a string. The string contains the exact hex codes in memory.

**My send hook function**

```
int WINAPI sendHook(SOCKET s, const char *buf, int len, int flags) {

    string packet = "3904050080841E00";
    return pSend(s, packet.c_str(), packet.length(), flags);
}
```

Comment: Should you be passing `packet.length()` instead of `len`?

Comment: The string contains the hex codes represented as ASCII characters. Is that what you're supposed to send? I somewhat doubt that. I would assume that that "39" means you're supposed to send a 39, not that you're supposed to send a `3` character followed by a `9` character. If that's true, then you string does *not* contain what you're supposed to send. Most likely you're supposed to send a 39, a 4, a 5, a 0, an 80, an 84, a 1E, and then another 0. Not the string "3904050080841E00". (Which, among other things, is twice as long.)

Comment: Thank you Tas for point that out. I've updated the code.

Comment: Does your problem still persist?

Comment: Yes, you are right David. How will I build the buffer? with 0x39, 0x4, 0x5, etc...

Comment: Yes, It still persist because I'm sending characters instead of sending the actual bytes. As david says.

Comment: It really depends where the hex is coming from in the first place. Usually, hex is used for human/machine interfaces. Why are you using it internally? You can certainly write code to convert the hex to binary if you have to.

Comment: I'm trying to send a different packet. After sending the original buffer. The hex should come from strings. So I need a function to convert my string to buffer without 0's

Comment: How can I do that David? convert string hex to binary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple.

```
const char[] packet = {0x39, 0x04, 0x05, 0x00, 0x80, 0x84, 0x1E, 0x00};
return pSend(s, packet, sizeof packet, flags);
```

Comment: EJP, it's now working. Thank you. How can I produce that kind of array buffer from a string? string given above.

Comment: Just parse it two bytes at a time as hex, but why? If it's a string literal, it's constant, so why not just code it directly as above? Why the string?

Comment: I just used a constant string in this example. But my program is using a dynamic string in my app. So, I have to find a way to convert string packets to char array buffers.